# WM_Html_GETOBJECT fail to retrieve Html object

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I try to get html object from a window, I was able to get the window element yet get nothing(return 0) when tried to get the hmtl object inside the window element.
Below is the code I used :

```
UIntPtr sendMessageResult = UIntPtr.Zero;

SendMessageTimeout(ieWindow, RegisterWindowMessage("WM_Html_GETOBJECT"), UIntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero,
                             SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,10000, out sendMessageResult);
```

ieWindow is my window element with Internet Explorer_Server

The code above will return me zero even I able to get IE element.

Thank you,